# Intent service AsyncTask background setAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a intent service and In this service I use an asytask on background I want to do this :                                                                                         `expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);`

But I can not do this

Comment: do it in onPostExecute().

Comment: Do you have a asyncTask inside a Service? Can you please provide more code?

Comment: @VictorNeves yes U have inside intent service an asyntask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit view from thread different from the activity thread.
I guess you're trying to do this in doInBackground (which is an other thread). To solve this issue you could execute this line in `onPreExecute()` method or `onPostExecute()`, executed respectively befor and after the `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`IntentService` launching a worker thread and you can't handle `View` on it. In general to touch `View` in background thread used `runOnUiThread();` or `Handler` with `Runnable` but runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached to. In my mind you choose wrong sollution and need to use callback from `Service` and update `View` inside `Activity` or `Fragment`